# Why do I get this warning in R if, the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r

I have below source code. The `if (is.na(monthData))` is used to check whether `monthData` is `NA`. If yes, assign it with an initial value.

```
monthData <- NA
if (category == 'QUARTER') {
  for (m in c(rep(1:4))) {
    md <- NA
    md <- queryDataForQuarter(year, str_c(m), kpi)
    if (is.na(monthData)) {
      monthData <- md[0,]
    }
    monthData[nrow(monthData) + 1,] <- md[1,]
  }
}
```

I got below warning when I run the code. What is wrong with my code?

`In if (is.na(monthData)) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: I cannot run your code. I specified category <- 'QUARTER' but I am still missing the function queryDataForQuarter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your first iteration `monthData` is a dataframe and the call `is.na(monthData)` will create a dataframe of logicals. The if statement only uses the first element of that dataframe, so in case `md[0,0]` would be `NA` you would initialize the `monthData` twice.

You could initialze `monthData` to `NULL` and then check for `length(monthData) == 0`

```
monthData <- NULL
if (category == 'QUARTER') {
  for (m in c(rep(1:4))) {
    md <- NA
    md <- queryDataForQuarter(year, str_c(m), kpi)
    if (length(monthData) == 0) {
      monthData <- md[0,]
    }
    monthData[nrow(monthData) + 1,] <- md[1,]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **If** function cannot be run on a vector of size more than 1. I presume `is.na(monthData)` contains more than one element. Check it out through debug mode 
 - use browser().

R gives a warning (and not an error) as it is accommodative (lenient) of small errors and there is a way out i.e. selecting the first element of the vector and moving on.